# Trying to loop through large string to find matching substrings

Tags: javascript

I have one large string with '----begin----' and '----end----' through out the string. I am trying to seperate out each message and display them all inside a div as seperate messages. The following code gets me the first one but I am struggling with the logic to loop through a large string with many messages. How do I loop through the entire large string? Thank you.

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');

function parseStr(str) {
  var start_idx = str.indexOf('------Begin Message------');
  var end_idx = str.indexOf('------End Message------');
  
  app.innerHTML += '<p>' + str.substring(start_idx, start_idx + 27) + '</p>' + '<p>' + 
    str.substring(start_idx + 27, end_idx) + '</p><p>' +
    str.substring(end_idx, end_idx + 23);
  
}

parseStr(str);
```

Comment: Could you show a sample string and the expected output? A [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the number `27` come from? The length of `"------Begin Message------"` equals `25`...?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If one of the answers helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This while-loop should go through all messages:

```
function parseStr(str) {
    let beginMsg = "------Begin Message------"
    let endMsg = "------End Message------"
    while ((let end_idx = str.indexOf(endMsg)) !== -1) {
        let start_idx = str.indexOf(beginMsg);
  
        /* start of your code */
        app.innerHTML += '<p>' +
            str.substring(start_idx, start_idx + beginMsg.length) + 
            '</p><p>' + str.substring(start_idx + beginMsg.length, end_idx) +
            '</p><p>' + str.substring(end_idx, end_idx + endMsg.length);
        /* end of your code */

        str = str.slice(end_idx + endMsg.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this approach works for you. I have no way of testing it, because your question doesn't provide a lot of information

Answer (score 0):

Below code will replace all your header and footer message text to `<p>` `</p>` tags giving you back a complete html string.

```
function parseStr(str) {
  let beginMsg = "------Begin Message------";
  let endMsg = "------End Message------";
  var re1 = new RegExp(beginMsg, "gi");
  var re2 = new RegExp(endMsg, "gi");
  str = str.replace(re1, "<p>").replace(re2, "</p>");
  return str;
}
```

OR if you want it this way

```
function parseStr(str) {
  let beginMsg = "------Begin Message------";
  let endMsg = "------End Message------";
  var re1 = new RegExp(beginMsg, "gi");
  var re2 = new RegExp(endMsg, "gi");
  str = str.replace(re1, "<div><p>"+beginMsg+"</p><p>").replace(re2, "</p><p>"+endMsg+"</p></div>");
  return str;
}
```

Comment: How do I loop the the large string?

Comment: you dont have to. check this codepen https://codepen.io/pranaynailwal/pen/dyNogxX?editors=1112
It will form the complete html for you. just provide the "large" string you have.

Answer (score 0):

"Large string" is a kind of trigger word for programmers. It matters if we're thinking megabytes, or just a few pages of text. In the "large, but not crazy large" case, just split on the delimiters.

```js
const bigString = "------Begin Message------This is a message------End Message------------Begin Message------This is another message------End Message------"
const startDelim = "------Begin Message------"
const endDelim = "------End Message------"

// use a regex with a conjunction start or ("|") end delimiter
let regex = new RegExp(`${startDelim}|${endDelim}`);
// split, then filter for the messages, processing each as a <p>
let messages = bigString.split(regex).reduce((acc, el, i) => {
  if (i%2) acc.push(`<p>${el}</p>`)
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(messages)
```

If it's truly large, you might not want it in memory, and you might not want all of the parsed pieces all in the dom at once.